# Powershell ISE F5 behavior for script module (.PSM1 file)

Tags: powershell-ise

When I'm editing a PowerShell script module (.psm1) in the ISE, and I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, nothing happens.  It doesn't even save the script module to disk, like it does if I'm editing a script (.ps1) file.

What I'd expect to have happen is for it to save the file (if dirty) and then execute a `Import-Module -Force` command for the module, and perhaps running some tests I've got defined for it.

I know there the ISE is extensible, is there a way to enhance the ISE to get this behavior for <kbd>F5</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

"PowerShell modules enable you to partition, organize, and abstract your Windows PowerShell code into self-contained, reusable units." - [Writing a Windows PowerShell Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878310(v=vs.85).aspx)

In order for you to run the code in your module, you need to import it through a regular PowerShell script, see [Windows PowerShell Module Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901839(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information

Comment: Thanks, but his really doesn't address my question, which was about ISE extensibility.